# IM001 Driver does not support this function (ODBC)

Tags: sql, odbc, database-connection

I'm building custom ODBC driver.

my main method:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    SQLRETURN status;
    //SQLHANDLE hEnv;
    //SQLHANDLE hStmt;
    SQLHENV hEnv;
    SQLHDBC dbc = 0;
    SQLHSTMT hStmt;
    SQLCHAR ConnStrOut[1024];

    SQLSMALLINT x;

    // startup banner
    //printf();

    MessageBox(GetDesktopWindow(), "ODBC Client\n\n", "Driver", MB_OK);

    // show query to be executed
    printf("Query: %s\n", "SELECT VISITS FROM TRAFFIC");

    // allocate ENVIRONMENT
    status = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &hEnv);

    // check for error
    ODBC_CHK_ERROR(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv, status, "");

    // set the ODBC version for behaviour expected
    status = SQLSetEnvAttr(hEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER) SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
    CHECK_STATUS(status, (UCHAR*)"SQLSetEnvAttr", hEnv, SQL_HANDLE_ENV);

    // check for error
    ODBC_CHK_ERROR(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv, status, "");

    // allocate CONNECTION
    status = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hEnv, &dbc);

    // check for error
    ODBC_CHK_ERROR(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv, status, "");


    // ----------- real connection takes place at this point 

   status = SQLDriverConnect(dbc, GetDesktopWindow(),
            (unsigned char*) "DSN=myDSN",
            SQL_NTS, ConnStrOut, 1024, &x,
            SQL_DRIVER_PROMPT);


    if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(status)) {
        printf("Connected\n");
        printf("Returned connection string was:\n\t%s\n", ConnStrOut);
        //SQLDisconnect(dbc);   
    }
```

Everything works well when I run main using my sample client.

However, when I try odbc testing tool odbcte32 or other odbc client(s) such as SqlDbx or QTODBC, once I try to establish connection using 'myDSN' (which is using my custom driver) I always get: **[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver does not support this function**

I've properly implemented SQLDriverConnect function to create OutConnectionString by reading key-value-pairs from User DSN that uses my compiled driver DLL.

I've defined skeletons for all odbc functions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714562(v=vs.85).aspx

I compile my custom diver using minGW compiler (32-bit). 
I have Windows 7 OS 64-bit but I'm running 32-bit ODBC test tool.

This is driving me crazy. I don't understand which specific function is not supported in my driver. Again, I have created skeletons for all needed functions. Here's the list:

SQLAllocConnect    ,
    SQLAllocEnv      ,
    SQLAllocStmt     ,
    SQLAllocHandle   ,
    SQLFreeConnect   ,
    SQLFreeEnv       ,
    SQLFreeStmt      ,
    SQLBindCol       ,
    SQLCancel        ,
    SQLConnect       ,
    SQLDescribeCol   ,
    SQLDisconnect    ,
    SQLExecDirect    ,
    SQLExecute       ,
    SQLExtendedFetch ,
    SQLFetch         ,
    SQLGetCursorName ,
    SQLNumResultCols ,
    SQLPrepare       ,
    SQLRowCount      ,
    SQLSetCursorName ,
    SQLColumns       ,
    SQLDriverConnect ,
    SQLGetData       ,
    SQLGetInfo       ,
    SQLGetTypeInfo   ,
    SQLParamData     ,
    SQLPutData       ,
    SQLStatistics    ,
    SQLTables        ,
    SQLBrowseConnect ,
    SQLColumnPrivileg,
    SQLDescribeParam ,
    SQLForeignKeys   ,
    SQLMoreResults   ,
    SQLNativeSql     ,
    SQLNumParams     ,
    SQLPrimaryKeys   ,
    SQLProcedureColum,
    SQLProcedures    ,
    SQLSetPos        ,
    SQLTablePrivilege,
    SQLBindParameter ,
    SQLCloseCursor   ,
    SQLColAttribute  ,
    SQLCopyDesc      ,
    SQLEndTran       ,
    SQLFetchScroll   ,
    SQLFreeHandle    ,
    SQLGetConnectAttr,
    SQLGetDescField  ,
    SQLGetDescRec    ,
    SQLGetDiagField  ,
    SQLGetDiagRec    ,
    SQLGetEnvAttr    ,
    SQLGetStmtAttr   ,
    SQLSetConnectAttr,
    SQLSetDescField  ,
    SQLSetDescRec    ,
    SQLSetEnvAttr    ,
    SQLSetStmtAttr   ,
    SQLBulkOperations,
    SQLSpecialColumns.

**EDIT:**

Figured it out. SQLDisconnect was defined incorrectly. Make sure all parameters that are passed are correct.
The right definition was:

```
RETCODE SQL_API SQLDisconnect(SQLHDBC pHandle) {
    __CHK_HANDLE(pHandle, SQL_HANDLE_DBC, SQL_ERROR);
    _SQLFreeDiag(_DIAGCONN(pHandle));
    _SQLDisconnect((PGENODBCCONN) pHandle);

    return (SQL_SUCCESS);
}
```

The way I figured it out:
create .def file (name it the same as your driver DLL file name, i.e. in my case it was axodbc.def), list all functions present in your driver in it, as following:

```
LIBRARY   axodbc
DESCRIPTION "Driver 1 definitions"
EXPORTS
    SQLAllocConnect
    SQLAllocEnv
    SQLAllocStmt
    SQLAllocHandle
    SQLFreeConnect
    SQLFreeEnv
    SQLFreeStmt
    SQLBindCol
    SQLCancel
    SQLConnect
    SQLDescribeCol
    SQLExecDirect
    SQLExecute
    SQLDisconnect
    SQLExtendedFetch
    SQLFetch
    SQLGetCursorName
    SQLNumResultCols
    SQLPrepare
    SQLRowCount
    SQLSetCursorName
    SQLColumns
    SQLDriverConnect
    SQLGetData
    SQLGetInfo
    SQLGetTypeInfo
    SQLParamData
    SQLPutData
    SQLStatistics
    SQLTables
    SQLBrowseConnect
    SQLColumnPrivileges
    SQLDescribeParam
    SQLForeignKeys
    SQLMoreResults
    SQLNativeSql
    SQLNumParams
    SQLPrimaryKeys
    SQLProcedureColumns
    SQLProcedures
    SQLSetPos
    SQLTablePrivileges
    SQLBindParameter
    SQLCloseCursor
    SQLColAttribute
    SQLCopyDesc
    SQLEndTran
    SQLFetchScroll
    SQLFreeHandle
    SQLGetConnectAttr
    SQLGetDescField
    SQLGetDescRec
    SQLGetDiagField
    SQLGetDiagRec
    SQLGetEnvAttr
    SQLGetStmtAttr
    SQLSetConnectAttr
    SQLSetDescField
    SQLSetDescRec
    SQLSetEnvAttr
    SQLSetStmtAttr
    SQLBulkOperations
    SQLSpecialColumns
```

Compile DLL (using mingw (g++)) and include your .def file, something like:

```
g++ -shared -o axodbc.dll axodbc.cpp connectionmanager.cpp diagnostics.cpp myresources.res axodbc.def -lodbc32 -lodbccp32
```

Compiler gave me an error at this point that SQLDisconnect was defined incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

I don't SQLGetFunctions in that list. You can always enable ODBC tracing in the driver manager and it will show what ODBC calls are made and what the result was.

Comment: SQLGetFunctions is defined by the `[Driver Manager]`. You don't need to rewrite it in your Driver.